# How do I get these two parts to merge?

Tags: mesh, extrude

I'm editing an .stl file to subdivide it for better 3D printing.  I've got multiple incidents of two parts that have a distance between them that needs to be bridged with new vertices/edges/faces (not sure which term is the most accurate to use).  Here's an example:

[image]

I need these parts to merge to be a solid cylinder.  I tried Mesh>Merge>At Center, but that didn't work out so well:

[image]

If these parts were aligned along an axis, for instance the Z-axis, then I would simply select the complete edge of either the upper or lower piece and extrude, but that's not the case.  How do I perfectly extrude geometry to make these two selections meet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And...I just figured it out.  Edit mode>Face>Fill.  It was that easy.

[image]

Comment: You could also have enabled the Looptools addon in Edit > Preferences > Addons and used the Looptools > Bridge entry on the right-click popup menu assuming both loops had the same number of vertices.

Comment: Good tip; thanks!

Comment: or simply *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*